# UPDATE SET FROM in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say you have two collections:

**collectionA**

- name
- description
- votes

**collectionB**

- collectionAId
- votes

I want to update all the votes in collectionA with the values in collectionB. If I was doing this with SQL I would do something like this:

```
update collectionA 
set collectionA.votes = collectionB.votes 
from collectionA 
inner join collectionB 
on collectionA._id = collectionB.collectionAId
```

The only way have found to do the equivalent of this with MongoDB is to use forEach or another client side cursor. With millions of documents, however, a client side cursor making millions of individual updates is extremely slow. How can I get this done in MongoDB with only 1 or a few client side calls and most of the work occurring on the actual database server?

Comment: the number of documents is in millions, however, what are the different distinct number of votes?  are they as varied as some have 1 some how thousands?  or do they tend to cluster with known min and maxes?

Comment: Sorry, I picked an arbitrary field to try and have a simple example. In my actual data, there are many fields with different data types. The basic gist is how to update one collection with data from another WITHOUT looping through a client side cursor.

Comment: you cannot do that. knowing what the data is/represents can provide ways to minimize the client work though.

Comment: Fiddlesticks. I know what you are saying in that if you are updating a field with 3 values you could reduce the client side update to just 3 multi updates. Unfortunately, that won't work in my case, though, because there are 10+ fields to update and some of them have ad hoc textual data. So, I need to "merge" each matching document between the two collections.

Comment: hmm - you can update multiple fields in a document in a single update. Can you give a more representative nature of data? And also, is this a one time operation or something that needs to be done periodically?